# How can I skip steps in bitbake compilation procedure?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Let's say I'm writing a recipe and would like disable for debugging e.g. `do_compile`, how can I achieve that? The recipe in question is compiling a C library.
I tried a few things such as overwriting:

```
do_compile() {
    pass
}
```

and leaving the function empty. But this did not skip the compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use:

```
do_compile[noexec] = "1"
```

See https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#deleting-a-task

Comment: Thanks! that looks like the bitbake-ish way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

While writing this question I found the answer myself: Add a `return` statement:

```
do_compile() {
    return

    # following compilation will not be seen by bitbake
}
```

Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to skip the do_compile:prepend() which was present in base recipe.

I had to add another do_compile:prepend() in bbappend, and add a return as coded below. This prepend will sit above base recipe prepend and because of return statement, further steps wont execute.

```
`do_compile:prepend() {
    return
    # skipping do_compile:prepend from base recipe which is not required.
}`
```